# %s in org-agenda-prefix-format doesn't display dates in the TODO view

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've been trying to add `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE` dates to the global TODO List in the org-mode-agenda (I'm using spacemacs).

From what I've read the variable to change should be `org-agenda-prefix-format`

In the help menu that I accessed through <kbd>C-h</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> it says these formatting characters work:

```
%c   the category of the item, "Diary" for entries from the diary,
       or as given by the CATEGORY keyword or derived from the file name
  %e   the effort required by the item
  %l   the level of the item (insert X space(s) if item is of level X)
  %i   the icon category of the item, see `org-agenda-category-icon-alist'
  %T   the last tag of the item (ignore inherited tags, which come first)
  %t   the HH:MM time-of-day specification if one applies to the entry
  %s   Scheduling/Deadline information, a short string
  %b   show breadcrumbs, i.e., the names of the higher levels
  %(expression) Eval EXPRESSION and replace the control string
                by the result
```

And by using `%?s` the field should only be shown if the value applies for the entry.

So I added the following line to my `.spacemacs` file:

```
(setq org-agenda-prefix-format "%?s ")
```

However this has no effect on the TODO list, but only on the weekly/daily agenda view.

Comment: Looks like `%s` is ignored in the TODO list: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12373/19819 (in comment). You could use an expression like `"%(let ((scheduled (org-get-scheduled-time (point)))) (if scheduled (format-time-string \"%Y-%m-%d\" scheduled) \"\")) "`

Comment: Your solution works fine. I just used a different time format and added `-18` after the `%` to have a fixed witdh. If you had posted it as an answer I'd have accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like **%s is ignored in the TODO list**: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12373/19819 (in comment).

Instead you can use a **custom expression**:

```lisp
"%(let ((scheduled (org-get-scheduled-time (point)))) (if scheduled (format-time-string \"%Y-%m-%d\" scheduled) \"\")) "
```

To just use this for the todo list modify the todo entry in `org-agenda-prefix-format` only:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-prefix-format
      '((agenda  . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s")
        (todo  . " %(let ((scheduled (org-get-scheduled-time (point)))) (if scheduled (format-time-string \"%Y-%m-%d\" scheduled) \"\")) %i %-12:c")
        (tags  . " %i %-12:c")
        (search . " %i %-12:c")))
```